# Is there a way to control the volume on Acer K272HUL monitors via Mac keyboard?

Tags: mac, display

Is there a way to control the volume on [Acer K272HUL](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/UM.HX2AA.001) monitors via Mac keyboard It seems like the only way to control volume is to use the controls on the monitor itself.

Answer (score 1):

The volume on the monitor controls the level of output for the speakers within the monitor.  The volume keys on a Mac keyboard control the volume of the sound the Mac outputs, so they are separate.

If you're connecting to the monitor from a Mac that has an HDMI port, the volume keys should ultimately alter the volume you hear coming out of the monitor, but it can't directly change the volume the monitor is set to.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work that way on HDMI.   Won't let me change the volume from HDMI and mini-DV.